# Python `aggdraw` module bug (?): visible alpha channel

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alpha-transparency, aggdraw

**Imagine simple script:**

```
from PIL import Image
from aggdraw import Draw, Brush

im = Image.new("RGBA", (600, 600), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = Draw(im)

brush = Brush("yellow")

draw.polygon(
             (
              50, 50,
              550, 60,
              550, 550,
              60, 550,
             ),
             None, brush
            )

draw.flush()
im.save("2.png")
```

**And the result:**
[image]

(Sorry for big size but that is more clearly)

**And the problem:**
Can you see non-yellow and non-white edges? This is the alpha-channel or something.

When I trying to do this only with `PIL`'s `Draw` object - it looks clearly and good but not anti-aliased.

But with `aggdraw`'s `Draw` object it looks anti-aliased but with that ugly dirty edges.

I need exactly polygons with non-standard side angles. Simple box is not what I want.

Please, help me with some good optimistic answer how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your background is black, but transparent. If you set your image background to white, you don't get the visible edges. Either transparent or solid white works in my simple tests.

Try these values:

```
transBlack = (0, 0, 0, 0)         # shows your example with visible edges
solidBlack = (0, 0, 0, 255)       # shows shape on a black background
transWhite = (255, 255, 255, 0)
solidWhite = (255, 255, 255, 255)

im = Image.new("RGBA", (600, 600), solidWhite)
```

Comment: of course, solid bg can handle this.
actually, I need only transparent white for all colors of polygon? or special one for some color?
using pycairo instead.

Comment: I don't understand your further questions. Transparent white should work, unless you can show me an example where it fails. You asked for "good optimistic answer" and suggestions, which I gave, but apparently you have more requirements which you didn't mention.